# problem with Wget in PHP

Tags: php, linux, shell, wget, opensuse

if I run the command in shell it will download it,No error by shell

but by PHP page always it goes to if statement

I tried `shell_exec` and the result is the same

I really want to do it just by `Wget`

But if this is impossible and your solution is `cURL` please tell it in more details then I can find out how to code it

```
$flag=system('wget -P /srv/www/htdocs/didebansnort/Downloads http://www.snort.org/reg-rules/snortrules-snapshot-2900.tar.gz/myoinkcodethatmustbesecret
');
if(!$flag)
{
echo '<script>alert("please try again!")</script>';
}
```

If the problem is about permissions How can I fix it?

suggestion was fopen 
but I have to download from command line
If you think it is possible!

here is the site

https://www.snort.org/snort-rules/#rules

well for example by rightclick on snortrules-snapshot-2904.tar.gz
I can have it
now I think it is impossible by fopen how can I make access to it?
I think solution is "just" download via command line in PHP
I don't know!

Thanks

Comment: It would scare me terribly if a 'sudo as root' command would go good from my .php

Comment: first I didn't write sudo but then I guess maybe permission is problem I can fix it by wwwrun n edit it but now my problem is sth else

Comment: On further reading, I have no idea what you're trying to achieve, sorry.  Do you want to do this via the command line (but in PHP?) or as part of a web page (which is why it's in PHP)?

Comment: snort is a software for users I should write something then users has not do anything in command line they will just click a button and then their rule files will be updated they don't need to know any code they will just click on a button

Comment: I wrote an application that made working with snort more easier now I have problem in update section

Comment: Yes I want to run a command line in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your PHP config allows you to execute system() and that it allows you to run it as root?

Comment: No if you try it some times it will download it and another point maybe your country is in filter area I have VPN do you have?

Comment: I have VPN and I can download it when I try it some times it is another problem that I can fix i but now my problem is just doing it by PHP

Comment: how can I fix it if I am not sure?

Answer (score 0):

Which user is the sudo running as? Does that user have passwordless access to root (if so, why!)  You really need to avoid the `sudo` bit, it's very probably failing.  Just make sure the user PHP runs as can write to /srv/www/htdocs/didebansnort/Downloads (understanding the risks there-of) and run the wget without the `sudo`.

Even better, why not use one of the built in methods of PHP to get a remote file? (`fopen`?)

Comment: I tried it without sudo but no result please tell me what do you mean with fopen I want to download a tar.gz file in the location that I wrote